# Using YahooQF to download stock Target Prices

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to be able to download target prices for stocks from yahoo finance into my R project. I note in the below thread that the yahooQF function has an argument called "1 yr Target Price" when the individual ran the yahooQF() call.

[How to get ETF Financial information (e.g. NAV) from Yahoo (with Quantmod)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741414/how-to-get-etf-financial-information-e-g-nav-from-yahoo-with-quantmod)

When i run that i don't get the same list of potential arguments

```
> yahooQF()

 1:   Symbol                                       2:   Name                                      
 3:   Name (Long)                                  4:   Quote Type                                
 5:   Quote Source Name                            6:   Source Interval                           
 7:   Currency                                     8:   Financial Currency                        
 9:   Market                                      10:   Market State                              
11:   Exchange                                    12:   Exchange Full Name                        
13:   Exchange Timezone                           14:   Exchange TZ                               
15:   Exchange Data Delay                         16:   GMT Offset Millis                         
17:   Tradeable                                   18:   Ask                                       
19:   Bid                                         20:   Ask Size                                  
21:   Bid Size                                    22:   Last Trade (Price Only)                   
23:   Last Trade Time                             24:   Change                                    
25:   Open                                        26:   Days High                                 
27:   Days Low                                    28:   Volume                                    
29:   Change in Percent                           30:   Previous Close                            
31:   Change From 52-week Low                     32:   Percent Change From 52-week Low           
33:   Change From 52-week High                    34:   Percent Change From 52-week High          
35:   52-week Low                                 36:   52-week High                              
37:   50-day Moving Average                       38:   Change From 50-day Moving Average         
39:   Percent Change From 50-day Moving Average   40:   200-day Moving Average                    
41:   Change From 200-day Moving Average          42:   Percent Change From 200-day Moving Average
43:   Market Capitalization                       44:   P/E Ratio                                 
45:   Price/EPS Estimate Next Year                46:   Price/Book                                
47:   Book Value                                  48:   Average Daily Volume                      
49:   Shares Outstanding                          50:   Ex-Dividend Date                          
51:   Dividend/Share                              52:   Dividend Yield                            
53:   Earnings Timestamp                          54:   Earnings Start Time                       
55:   Earnings End Time                           56:   Earnings/Share                            
57:   EPS Forward                                 58:   Language                                  
59:   Message Board ID                            60:   Price Hint                                

Enter one or more numbers separated by spaces, or an empty line to cancel
1:
```

Is it because the version of quantmod used in the above thread is different from my version?

I've gone to github to see Joshua Ulrich's version of the package and downloaded the devtools version of quantmod to make sure i have latest version, and it still produces the above list of arugments.

Below is the code i'm running

```
devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod")
library(quantmod)
library(plyr)

metrics <- yahooQF(c("P/E Ratio", "1 yr Target Price"))

symbols <- c("MSFT", "AAPL", "FB", "GOOG")

Target_Price_1yr <- getQuote(paste(symbols, sep="", collapse=";"), src = "yahoo", what=metrics)

Target_Price_1yr

           Trade Time P/E Ratio
MSFT 2019-11-04 16:00:01  27.27358
AAPL 2019-11-04 16:00:01  21.65686
FB   2019-11-04 16:00:01  31.13030
GOOG 2019-11-04 16:00:01  27.71121
```

I expect to see the 1 yr Target Price for the stock (i assume it's an average value of all the analysts estimates) but nothing appears. Is there a way with quantmod to get this information from yahoo finance or is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

That field was deprecated 2 years ago when yahoo switched from csv to json API and hasn't been readded it seems:
https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/commit/5f60d497d9d50dfb78d4290493b8669d477e0911

Comment: Many thanks - do you know if there are any other ways of accessing analysts target prices through a free data source like yahoo finance?

Comment: no sorry, nothing that I wouldn't have to google myself either :)